# Conditional Shortcode image display

Tags: conditional-content, shortcode

Got a problem with a shortcode.. i probebly dont know where & how to set the condition so it will display the right image according to the topic / category of the toturial..

Help Plz :)

```
function postInfoBoxSc( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'subject' => 'Category type',
        'difficulty' => 'User Types',
        'completiontime' => 'completion Time'
    ), $atts ) );

        // Set image acorring to guide type
        if ($subject == 'wordpress') {
            $subjectImg = '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/postInfoBox/wordpress.png" alt="מדריך וורדפרס" />';
        } elseif ($subject == 'web design') {
            $subjectImg = '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/postInfoBox/webDesign.png" alt="מדריך בניית אתרים" />';
        } elseif ($subject == 'facebook') {
            $subjectImg = '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/postInfoBox/facebook.png" alt="מדריך פייסבוק" />';
        } elseif ($subject == 'RSS') {
            $subjectImg = '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/postInfoBox/rss.png" alt="מדריך RSS" />';
        }

    return '
    <br class="clear" />
    <div class="postInfoBox">
        '. $subjectImg .'
        <h5>Guide information:</h5>
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Category:</strong> '. $subject .'</li>

                    <li><strong>User Lever:</strong> '. $difficulty .'</li>

                    <li><strong>completion Time:</strong> '. $completiontime .'</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    ';
}
add_shortcode( 'postInfoBox', 'postInfoBoxSc' );
```

**The Problem**
For some reason the value of $subject doesent get updated like the othere values and isnt being passed trough the shortcode and the image isn't changing because of that

**What Am I Doing Wrong ??**

(just added per request)
this is the shortcode i am entreing in wordpress editor when writing a post:

```
[postInfoBox subject="somthing" difficulty="hard" completiontime="2-5 minuts"]
```

Comment: What's your current outcome and expected outcome?

Comment: currently i am getting the 'wordpress' as the value of $subject.. i want the value to change when entereing the shortcode like this:
[postInfoBox subject="somthing" difficulty="hard" completiontime = "2-5 minuts"]  ... see any reason why it doesent do that ?

Comment: also i would like the image to change according to the entered value of $subject (see the if condition)..

Comment: Unless you paste here the actual text you are testing on and output... I can't help. Your code seems OK, but with no test text... I can't tell.

Comment: Agreed with @EarnestoDev: we need to see the *actual shortcode text* being used.

Comment: i did :)

**[postInfoBox subject="somthing" difficulty="hard" completiontime = "2-5 minuts"]**

Comment: the code works as expected in my local test setup - always prints the right 'subject' text and prints the right img tag and img link if 'subject' matches one of the conditions. possibly an interference with some plugin (?)

Comment: Hmm.. i should have realy tested it on a clean theme.. thanks for the tip.. going to run it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to replicate your problem exactly, but here's a tip: include some default behavior, in case the user puts in a bad value for the subject:

```
    // Set image acorring to guide type
    if ($subject == 'wordpress') {
        $subjectImg = '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/postInfoBox/wordpress.png" alt="מדריך וורדפרס" />';
    } elseif ($subject == 'web design') {
        $subjectImg = '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/postInfoBox/webDesign.png" alt="מדריך בניית אתרים" />';
    } elseif ($subject == 'facebook') {
        $subjectImg = '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/postInfoBox/facebook.png" alt="מדריך פייסבוק" />';
    } elseif ($subject == 'RSS') {
        $subjectImg = '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/postInfoBox/rss.png" alt="מדריך RSS" />';
    } else {
        // Add default case
        $subject = "Default here";
        $subjectImg = '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/postInfoBox/default.png" alt="מדריך RSS" />';
    }
```

That way, there will always be an image even if they give you bad data.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!